# For getting location didUpdateLocations is not hitting on real devcie swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, location, currentlocation

I need to get current location but when i allow location access and run code it is not hitting on didUpdateLocations method instead it hits on didFailWithError on iphone 6. I have added details required in plist also. Please help me to debugg whether the issue is in my code.

Here is the code

```
 func determineCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
          locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
   
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(manager.location!.coordinate)
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Location data not enabled")
    }
```

In plist i added
Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

This is the error printed
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Comment: What is the error you get? You should print it instead of just printing a fixed string.

Comment: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` means that location services are enabled on the device, not that the user gave the authorization to use it.

Check the authorization with `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` and eventually ask the user to give it.